# UITableView blank space not working?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, text-alignment

so I was trying to align the text in UITableView using. 
cell.textLabel?.text = sometext

I have two part in sometext first part is words, second part is number, such as "apple 45" "pear 23", "banana 34"so when they are showing in tableview cell, I want the left side of the words align with each other and the left side the number align with each other. and I can not post a picture here.

so according to the first part word length I added some blank space in the string by appending

```
let appStr = String(count: 22-cnt, repeatedValue: ( " " as Character))
print("append string is" + appStr + "end")
nameHere = name + appStr + number
```

I printed out to console in the program and it works fine, but when showing in the simulator it is not aligned.

Comment: "and the left side the number align with each other" Don't you mean the right side?

Comment: No..I mean LEFT side

Comment: So you want `134` to stick out further _to the right_ than `2`? You want the `2` under the `1` of `134`? That is a very unusual way to display a column of numbers.

Comment: Really appreciate it.  I want to 2 in 23 under 1 in 124, so left of them align. cause  I have a Input box above the tableview, so I want them to align the box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't attempt to align numbers using spaces. Set the label's `attributedText`, not its `text`, and use the fact that an NSAttributedString can have tab stops to perform the alignment.

Comment: Or use two labels, so that the layout doesn't get mangled if there's one long word or the app gets localized to another language.

Comment: Really appreciate it. Looks like using NSAttributedString didnt work. I added different taps for different length of words, they came out the same as using string. maybe I need to clear something. I removed the app from the memory and did it again.

Comment: Thanks Ant. I finically solved it by create a custom UITableviewcell with two labels. I think that is the most elegant way.